# wget returns a 3 bytes home page

Tags: wget

I am trying to download a webpage at www.oabt.org. With browser, it works ok to get all the html code, but with wget I get only a 3 bytes page.

```
➜  spider git:(master) wget http://www.oabt.org/
--2013-02-06 01:45:11--  http://www.oabt.org/
Resolving www.oabt.org... 125.64.93.243
Connecting to www.oabt.org|125.64.93.243|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’


100%[===============================================================================>] 3           --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-02-06 01:45:12 (117 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [3/3]

➜  spider git:(master) ✗ xxd -l 100 ./index.html 
0000000: efbb bf
```

How to get the homepage properly for this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dumped the http connections with `wireshark` and i made a diff between headers sent by `wget` and the ones sent by the `browser`. I tried to replicate the same http request playing with wget's `--header` parameters until i discovered the website needs the `Accept-Encoding: gzip` header to reply properly.

In a nutshell the working command become:

```
 wget --header='Accept-Encoding: gzip' http://www.oabt.org/index.php
```

BUT this will save a `gzipped` content...

If you want to decompress the page on the fly use this command:

```
wget -O- --header='Accept-Encoding: gzip' \
http://www.oabt.org/index.php | gunzip - > index.html
```

... and the gzipped content will be decompressed and redirected to `index.html` file

Comment: +100! Good effort in understanding and addressing the issue!

Comment: It works! Thanks for the effort!